# expand slice to be from first element in array that contains string 'NN'

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code that gets a splice of an array from the start value, which is calculated to be the first word that contains IN, then to the end value, which is calculated to be the last word that contains NN.

How can I get the start value to be the first word that contains NN if the array has a word that contains NN and after that a word that contains IN. then the end value will be as normal, the last instance of NN.

```
var first = theTopic.split(' ').reduce(function(p, c, i){
    return p != -1 ? p : c.indexOf('IN') != -1 ? i : -1;
}, -1);
var last = theTopic.split(' ').reduce(function(p, c, i, a){
    return c.indexOf('NN') != -1 ? i : p;
}, -1);
if(theTopic.indexOf('IN') > -1){
    lastLocation = (theTopic.split(' ').slice(first, last + 1)).join(' ').replace(/,|\(.*?\)/g, ''));
}
```

So currently, if the array looks like: `["PB", "IN", "NN"]`, lastLocation is set to ["IN", "NN"]. Also currently if the array looks like: `["LL", "XC", "NN", "IN", "NN"]`, lastLocation will be set to ["IN", "NN"].

What I want is that if there is an "NN" followed by and "IN", such as in `["LL", "XC", "NN", "IN", "NN"]`, then lastLocation is set to `["NN", "IN", "NN"]`;

Comment: For these type of question is convenient that you post an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @elclanrs okay, I edited the question with input and wanted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already did most of the work -

once you found the first "IN" just go back and see if there was an "NN" before it - if there was update the 'first' to point to it.

But you dont need all these complex reduce code - you can use array `indexOf` for first and `lastIndexOf` for last.

try this:

```
var theTopic = "LL XC NN IN NN";
var tokens = theTopic.split(' ');
var last_index = tokens.lastIndexOf('NN');  // the last NN
var in_index = tokens.indexOf('IN');  // the IN
var first_index = tokens.lastIndexOf('NN', in_index); // search for last 'NN' before last 'IN'
var result = tokens.slice(first_index, last_index+1).join(' ')
```

*edit*: `lastIndexOf` is not supported by IE8 and below - if you want IE7-IE8 support you can add this polyfill code once before your list slicing code runs:

```
[].lastIndexOf || (Array.prototype.lastIndexOf = function(a,b){for(++b>0?0:b=this.length+~~b;~--b&&(!(b in this)||this[b]!==a););return b}
```